# Можно ли делать кольцо с двумя сетевыми картами у сервера?

Tags: сеть

Если у сервера есть две сетевые карты, и подсоединить одну к одному коммутатору, а другую к другому, при этом образовывается кольцо, так как оба коммутатора подсоединены к третьему, то можно ли как то настроить чтобы все работало нормально. Нужно чтобы сервер был частью обеих рабочих групп.

Comment: А зачем вам вторая сетевуха. раз у вас 2 коммутатора соединены с третьим - то у вас и так одна общая сеть. А некие "рабочие группы" это уже из терминологии windows не ясно что вы под этим понимаете. Но несколько виндовых рабочих групп отлично работают в одной сети (и по одной сетевухе)

Comment: Это не кольцо. И при такой схеме всё работает. Кольцо возникнет если у Вас не сервер, а четвёртый коммутатор.

Comment: @Mike я хочу чтобы обе сети имели доступ к серверу, но обе сети уже соединены третьим коммутатором. Я не хочу подключать сервер к третьему коммутатору.

Comment: @van9petryk Если два коммутатора соединены между собой - то по сути это один большой коммутатор. Сеть одна. Если вы соединяете две сети коммутором - то по сути вы делаете из них одну общую сеть. Так что поясните, прочему вы считаете их отдельными сетями.

Comment: @Mike ок, не сети, а подсети. У меня есть два отдела, у каждой свой коммутатор, обе подсети нужно подклчить к двум серверам, 
Более конкретно тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/605763/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%85

Вообщем, можно закольцевать сеть так, чтобы нижний сервер использовало два отдела, но пакеты пересылать через него не надо.

Comment: Все равно не ясно в чем вопрос. Как вам уже сказали выше, тут кольца нет и следовательно так делать можно. Причем рабочие оба ваши варианта из второго вопроса

Comment: @Mike вот это я и хотел узнать, что первый вариант рабочий и так делать можно. Я думал что у нас образуется кольцо. Но вот смотрите, у меня на верхнем сервере программный маршрутизатор. Если я сделаю еще маршрутизатор на нижнем сервере то кольца тоже не будет или будет?

Comment: Через маршрутизатор кольца, вредного для работы сети, быть не может в принципе. Если маршрутизатора два, то может быть ситуация, что пакет от клиента A к клиенту B пойдет через маршрутизтор1, а пакет от B к A пойдет через маршрутизатор2, в общем по пакеты идут кругом, но это нормальная рабочая ситуация, к штормам она не приводит. Вредные кольца образуются только если вы закольцуете коммутаторы, без маршрутизаторов. т.е. между любыми двумя коммуторами в сети должно быть не более одного не маршрутизируемого пути

Comment: @Mike ок, спасибо вам, вы мне помогли